# Running into an issue while using sjplot and subset function in logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, sjplot

Issue solved: I updated my R from 4.2.0 to 4.2.1 and the issue was solved autonomically. Anyone who ran into the similar problem could try this first.

I am trying use the "subset" function to remove the outliers from my model based on standardized residual of the model. However I ran into an error that while using sjPlot::tab_model. The error is as beneath.

```
Error in vectbl_as_row_location(i, nr, i_arg, assign) : 
ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
✖ Input has size 2560 but subscript `r` has size 1006.
```

Q. May I know how to fix this?

This is my model:

```
model_2 <- glmer (score~ TIME+ READING_ABILITY + (PARITICIPANT) + (1| WORD), family = binomial (link = "logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), data = MY_DATA, subset = abs(scale(resid(model))) <2.5)

sjPlot::tab_model (model_2)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thank you @Quiten. It seems that the sjPlot did not work well the  R version 4.2.0. I have updated my R to 4.2.1 and the issue was solved.